# What does "too generic" type system mean?

Tags: scala

Referring to the following tutorial https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html, `foo[A,B]` will not compile because it is 'too generic'. I do not understand what 'too generic' implies. Why does `foo` doesn't compile but `foo1` does?

```
scala> def foo[A,B](f: A=>List[A], b:B) = f(b)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : b.type (with underlying type B)
 required: A
       def foo[A,B](f: A=>List[A], b:B) = f(b)
                                            ^

scala> def foo1[A](f: A=>List[A], b:A) = f(b)
foo1: [A](f: A => List[A], b: A)List[A]
```

Comment: You're trying to supply a value with type `B` to a function of type `A => List[A]`.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose thats why this works  (I specify explicit conversion from `B` to `A` - `def foo[A,B](f: A=>List[A], f2: B=>A, b:B) = f(f2(b))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `f` is `A => List[A]`. This means that `f` can only be called with an argument of type `A`. Therefore `b` must be of type `A` for `f(b)`. `b: B` is too generic in the sense that you allow `b` to be of any type, not just `A`.

Consider for example the following function:

```
def wrapInt(i: Int): List[Int] = List(i)
```

Now the following call is legal:

```
wrapInt(42)
```

But this one is not

```
wrapInt("hello")
```

because `"hello"` is not an `Int`. Therefore this should be allowed:

```
foo(wrapInt, 42)
```

, but this should not:

```
foo(wrapInt, "hello")
```

According to the signature `def foo[A,B](f: A=>List[A], b:B)`, both would be allowed even though the the latter would lead to `wrapInt("hello")`, which is ill-typed. Therefore that signature is illegal for that body.

Comment: OK. I assumed that compiler would assume that `B` must be equal to `A`. I understand that compiler sees that `B` might not be equal to `A` so for the code to work (compile), either I should keep only `A` or provide a conversion from `B` to `A`. That is why this works `scala> def foo[A,B](f: A=>List[A], b:B)(implicit f2: B=>A) = f(b)`